# insert into database using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, backend

i have this form:

```
  <div className="form-group">
    <label>First Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="fname" className={`form- 
    control${this.state.fnameMandatory ? ' bg-danger' : ''}`} value= 
    {this.state.fname}  onChange = {this.handleNameChange}/>
     <p className="text-danger">{this.state.fnameMandatory}</p>
    </div>

   <div className="form-group">
   <label>last Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="lname" className={`form- 
       control${this.state.fLnameMandatory ? ' bg-danger' : ''}`} value= 
       {this.state.lname}  onChange = {this.handleLNameChange}/>
      <p className="text-danger">{this.state.fLnameMandatory}</p>
    </div>
<div className="col-xs-6">

        <input type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.handleSaveBtn} value="save" />
    </div>
```

can anyone help me how to insert into database using vb.net?

i made this:

```
 Function Save(ByRef _data As String) As String Implements IDataService.Save

    Dim strsql As StringBuilder
    Dim cnsql As SqlConnection
    Dim cmsql As SqlCommand
    Dim myvalue As String

    Try

        cnsql = New SqlConnection(lcConSql)
        cnsql.Open()

        strsql = New StringBuilder

        With strsql
            .Append("INSERT INTO tbl_students (st_firstName, st_lastName, st_gender, st_email) VALUES (// i dont know what to put in here)")
        End With

        cmsql = New SqlCommand(strsql.ToString, cnsql)
```

im new to vb and i dont know how to insert into database...any help plz? thanks in advance

Comment: Just put all proper values after `VALUES` keyword, separated by comma. If you want to pass values from VB.NET variables, use parameterized query with `SqlParameter`.

Comment: can you give me an example? @TetsuyaYamamoto

Comment: `INSERT INTO tbl_students (st_firstName, st_lastName, st_gender, st_email) VALUES ('A', 'B', 'Male', 'xxx@example.com')`. The values are depends on data type used on each column. If you want to use parameters, use something like `VALUES (@stFirstName, @stLastName, @stGender, @stEmail)`.

Comment: ok but how to declare @stFirstName etc...

Comment: Use `SqlParameter` as I said before: `cmsql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stFirstName", "A")`. If you want to specify parameter type, use like `cmsql.Parameters.Add("@paramName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "value"`.

Comment: Maybe I mistake, but You need to put `runat="server"` into every `<input type="text"...` so You can take values in backend code. eg. `<input type="text" runat="server" ...`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `StringBuilder` for this.

```
cmsql.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tbl_students (st_firstName, st_lastName, st_gender, st_email) VALUES (@FirstName,@LastName,@Gender,@Email)"

cmsql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", "John")
cmsql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", "Doe")
cmsql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", "M")
cmsql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", "johndoe@email.com")

cmsql.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: Actually, it is a StringBuilder that the OP used. StringBuilder is not necessary for a single string. It helps when you are changing a string repeatedly which really throws out the old string and replaces it with a brand new string. The StringBuilder prevents all this thrashing about by being mutable.

Answer (score 0):

I have created an SQL Connector Class to be able to easily connect to a database and then you can execute commands and get records from a database. I haven't tried it on anything except for SSMS (Microsoft's Database), but it should work for it.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Class sqlConnector
    Private con As SqlConnection
    Public hasSetup As Boolean = False

    Public Sub Setup(ByVal dataSource As String, ByVal initialCatalog As String, ByVal username As String, ByVal password As String)
        Dim connectionString As String = String.Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};User ID={2};Password={3};", dataSource, initialCatalog, username, password)
        con = New SqlConnection(connectionString)

        Try
            con.Open()
            con.Close()
            hasSetup = True
        Catch e As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("There was an error connecting to the server, " & e.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Sub Execute(ByVal sqlString As String)
        con.Open()
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sqlString, con)
        cmd.ExecuteScalar()
        con.Close()
    End Sub

    Public Function GetFirstRow(ByVal sqlString As String) As String()
        con.Open()
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sqlString, con)
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        reader.Read()
        Dim returnData As String() = New String(reader.FieldCount - 1) {}

        For i As Integer = 0 To reader.FieldCount - 1
            returnData(i) = reader(i).ToString()
        Next

        con.Close()
        Return returnData
    End Function

    Public Function GetSingleValue(ByVal sqlString As String) As String
        con.Open()
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sqlString, con)
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        reader.Read()
        Dim returnData As String
        returnData = reader(0).ToString()
        con.Close()
        Return returnData
    End Function

    Public Function GetDataTable(ByVal sqlString As String) As DataTable
        con.Open()
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sqlString, con)
        Dim reader As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim returnData As DataTable = New DataTable()
        reader.Fill(returnData)
        con.Close()
        Return returnData
    End Function

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports MySqlConnector

Class MainWindow

    Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)

        Dim mydatatable As datatable = MyRst("select * from clienti")
        Dim mynewrow As DataRow = mydatatable.NewRow
        mynewrow("NUME") = text1.Text
        mynewrow("PRENUME") = text2.Text
        mynewrow("AN") = text3.Text
        mynewrow("DATA_EXPIRARE") = text4.Text
        mydatatable.Rows.Add(mynewrow)
        MyRstUpdate(mydatatable, "clienti")
        mylistboxPriva.Items.Clear()
        Dim myGridView As New GridView
        myGridView.AllowsColumnReorder = False

        For Each item As DataColumn In mydatatable.Columns

            Dim myNewColumn As New GridViewColumn

            myNewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding = New Binding(item.ColumnName)
            myNewColumn.Header = item.ColumnName
            myGridView.Columns.Add(myNewColumn)

        Next
        mylistboxPriva.View = myGridView
        For Each item As DataRow In mydatatable.Rows
            mylistboxPriva.Items.Add(New With {Key .ID = item.ItemArray(0), Key .NUME = item.ItemArray(1), Key .PRENUME = item.ItemArray(2), Key .AN = item.ItemArray(3), Key .DATA_EXPIRARE = item.ItemArray(4)})
        Next

    End Sub

    Public Function MyRst(strSQL As String) As DataTable

        Dim rstData As New DataTable
        Using conn As New MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;User ID=root;Database=bazadedate")
            Using cmdSQL As New MySqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
                conn.Open()
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
                rstData.TableName = strSQL

            End Using
        End Using

        Return rstData
    End Function


    Public Sub MyRstUpdate(rstData As DataTable, strTableName As String)

        Using conn As New MySqlConnection("Server=LOCALHOST;User ID=root;Database=bazadedate")
            Using cmdSQL As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * from " & strTableName, conn)

                Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL)
                Dim daUP As New MySqlCommandBuilder(da)
                conn.Open()
                da.Update(rstData)
            End Using
        End Using

    End Sub

    Public myvar
    Private Sub DataGrid_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As SelectionChangedEventArgs)

    End Sub

    Private Sub text2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As TextChangedEventArgs) Handles text2.TextChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub DELETE_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles DELETE.Click
        Dim mydatatable As DataTable = MyRst("select * from clienti")
        Dim myselectedindex = mylistboxPriva.SelectedIndex
        mydatatable.Rows(myselectedindex).Delete()
        MyRstUpdate(mydatatable, "clienti")

        mydatatable = MyRst("select * from clienti")
        mylistboxPriva.Items.Clear()
        Dim myGridView As New GridView
        myGridView.AllowsColumnReorder = False

        For Each item As DataColumn In mydatatable.Columns

            Dim myNewColumn As New GridViewColumn

            myNewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding = New Binding(item.ColumnName)
            myNewColumn.Header = item.ColumnName
            myGridView.Columns.Add(myNewColumn)

        Next
        mylistboxPriva.View = myGridView
        For Each item As DataRow In mydatatable.Rows
            mylistboxPriva.Items.Add(New With {Key .ID = item.ItemArray(0), Key .NUME = item.ItemArray(1), Key .PRENUME = item.ItemArray(2), Key .AN = item.ItemArray(3), Key .DATA_EXPIRARE = item.ItemArray(4)})
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub myListBox_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles mylistboxPriva.Loaded

        Dim mydatatable As DataTable = MyRst("select * from clienti")


        Dim myGridView As New GridView
        myGridView.AllowsColumnReorder = False

        For Each item As DataColumn In mydatatable.Columns

            Dim myNewColumn As New GridViewColumn

            myNewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding = New Binding(item.ColumnName)
            myNewColumn.Header = item.ColumnName
            myGridView.Columns.Add(myNewColumn)

        Next
        mylistboxPriva.View = myGridView
        For Each item As DataRow In mydatatable.Rows
            mylistboxPriva.Items.Add(New With {Key .ID = item.ItemArray(0), Key .NUME = item.ItemArray(1), Key .PRENUME = item.ItemArray(2), Key .AN = item.ItemArray(3), Key .DATA_EXPIRARE = item.ItemArray(4)})
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub mylistboxPriva_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As SelectionChangedEventArgs) Handles mylistboxPriva.SelectionChanged

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).